# Terminate Running Python Apps

Tags: python, linux, ssh

I have a Raspberry Pi running Raspbian controlling a home automation system as part of a project for college. To control this I'm using an ASP.NET web app to fire SSH commands at the Pi to start various Python apps. I need a way to terminate another app over SSH before starting a new one.

For example:

a.py and b.py are running

User selects c.py from the web app

a.py must be stopped before starting c.py leaving b.py and c.py running.

Thanks

Jake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to kill every running instance of python:

```
$ kill `pidof python`
```

If you want to kill every running instance of a specific python script:

```
$ kill `pidof -x myscript.py`
or
$ pkill myscript.py
or
$ killall glances
```

It's generally not advisable to send SIGKILL to a running program (`kill -9`). SIGTERM is usually sufficient unless the program is frozen. All the above commands send SIGTERM.

Answer (score 0):

find the PID (Process ID) of your python script using the command (should be the second column)

```
ps -ef | grep python
kill <PID found previously>
kill -9 <PID found previously>
```

If the program is still running then it means you are using the wrong PID
Nothing can stop a kill -9 command :-)

Comment: Thanks, would the PID remain the same every time? If not, what would the best way be to do this programmatically?

Comment: @JoranBeasley I edited the title of my question to better reflect what I need. That command looks like it would end every python script running.